# Corrupt/truncated mp4 upload to S3 bucket using NodeJS and AWS S3

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, fs

I'm using fs.readFile to read in a local mp4 file of around 700KB, and AWS SDK to load the file onto my S3 bucket. The process works, but the file is corrupt, presumably truncated because the size of the resulting file on S3 is only around 500KB.

The code I'm using works for images just fine. Just not working for mp4 files. Here's my code:

```
fs.readFile(file_location, function (err, data) {
    if (err) { 
        console.log('fs error': err);
    } else {
        var base64data = new Buffer(data, 'binary');

        var params = {
            Bucket: config.settings.bucket, 
            Key: 'file.mp4', 
            Body: base64data,
            ContentEncoding: 'base64',
            ContentType: 'video/mp4'
        };

        s3.putObject(params, function(err, data) {
            if (err) { 
                console.log('Error putting object on S3: ', err); 
            } else { 
                console.log('Placed object on S3: ', object_key); 
            }  
        });
    }
});
```

I've tried omitting the ContentEncoding and/or the ContentType properties from the params object.

EDIT:

So when I did a console.log of the length of the data that fs.readFile returned, it consistently comes up short. I didn't realize I wasn't actually handling base64 data, either. So if I use the following code where I ask to read the file in using base64, the data.length from fs.readFile appears to be correct, and an mp4 file shows up on my S3 bucket with a playhead in the browser (which I wasn't getting before), but the video won't play & it's black, so it appears to still be corrupt.

```
fs.readFile(file_location, 'base64', function (err, data) {
    if (err) { 
        console.log('fs error': err);
    } else {
        var params = {
            Bucket: config.settings.bucket, 
            Key: 'file.mp4', 
            Body: data,
            ContentEncoding: 'base64',
            ContentType: 'video/mp4'
        };

        s3.putObject(params, function(err, data) {
            if (err) { 
                console.log('Error putting object on S3: ', err); 
            } else { 
                console.log('Placed object on S3: ', object_key); 
            }  
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Is the file on disk actually encoded in base64? I highly doubt it. If it's an mp4 that's a binary format and telling node to read it as if it is base64 is going to cause corruption. Just read it as binary from disk and let the amazon library stream it to s3 as binary. When you pass an encoding to `fs.readFile` that says "the data in this file is in this encoding", it does not do any conversion, so if that encoding is not actually true you'll have corruption.

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me, Peter. I didn't fully understand that you were describing not needing base64 encoding at all. I crafted my attempt from a tutorial that involved pulling data that was in fact base64 encoded, but my local files (of course) were not. Works fine now.

Comment: @Gregir Could you please help me? I have the same issue of file corruption on s3 via nodejs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `data` variable you get back from `readFile` is already good to go. Just pass that directly on with `Body: data`. Drop the `ContentEncoding` param entirely as you are not sending base64 data.